# Получить имя класса

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

Мне нужно для логирования получить имя текущего класса. Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666802/is-there-a-class-macro-in-c) советуют делать так

```cpp
void MyNS::CMyClassImpl::Test() {
  std::cout << typeid(*this).name();
}
```

Проблема в том, что для класса

```cpp
namespace MyNS {
    class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMyClassImpl :
            public ATL::CComObjectRoot,
            public ATL::CComCoClass<CMyClassImpl, &CLSID_CoMyClass>,
            public ATL::IDispatchImpl<IMyClass, &IID_IMyClass, &LIBID_rsMyLib, 1, 0>,
            public CComISupportErrorInfoImpl<&IID_IMyClass>
    {
        void Test();
    }
}
```

Я получаю строку

```cpp
class ATL::CComObject<class MyNS::CMyClassImpl>
```

Два вопроса:

1. Почему?
2. Хотелось бы получить `CMyClassImpl` или хотя бы `MyNS::CMyClassImpl`, а потом натравить парсер.

Все это для Visual Studio

**Update**

Макроса `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` в VS нет. А `__FUNCTION__` возвращает `MyNS::CMyClassImpl::MyMethod`. Если не будет других вариантов, то буду использовать его

Comment: *"Почему?"* - когда отсутствует [mcve], получить можно что угодно, и никто этого проверить не сможет. А для получения имени класса делайте в классе соответствующую статическую функцию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Почему?

`typeid(*this)` возвращает id не текущего типа, а id финального класса иерархии (экземпляр которого был создан). ATL не может создать экземпляр непосредственно класса CMyClassImpl, поскольку это абстрактный класс. Вместо этого он создает `ATL::CComObject<CMyClassImpl>`, в котором определены недостающие абстрактные функции.

Если нужно узнать какой тип имеет `*this` в текущем контексте, пишите `typeid(decltype(*this))`. (remove_c_v, добавлять по вкусу.)

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение

Comment: Глупый вопрос: а `remove_cv` куда вставлять?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось так

```cpp
std::string getClassName(const std::string & methodName) {
    size_t pos = methodName.find(' ');
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
        return "";
    if (methodName.substr(0, pos) != "class")
        return "";
    size_t startPos = methodName.rfind("::");
    if (startPos == std::string::npos)
        startPos = pos;
    else
        startPos += 2;
    return methodName.substr(startPos);
}

#define __CLASS__ getClassName(typeid(decltype(*this)).name())
```